# Speex voice chat: EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash when trying to decode

Tags: c, exc-bad-access, speex

I'm developing a voice chat and I used speex to compress the data that is being transmitted.
But I encountered a crash when I try to decode the received data.
I compress the data using this code:

Init method (runs only one time):

```
/*Create a new encoder state in narrowband mode*/
state = speex_encoder_init(&speex_nb_mode);

/*Set the quality to 8 (15 kbps)*/
int tmp=8;
speex_encoder_ctl(state, SPEEX_SET_QUALITY, &tmp);

speex_bits_init(&bits);
```

Compress method:

```
AudioBuffer sourceBuffer = bufferList->mBuffers[0];
speex_bits_reset(&bits);
/*Encode the frame*/
speex_encode(state, sourceBuffer.mData, &bits);
char cbits[200];
int nbBytes = speex_bits_write(&bits, cbits, 200);

NSData *result = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cbits length:200];
```

Decompress method:

```
NSLog(@"Lenght %d", [data length]);
speex_bits_reset(&bits);

/*Copy the data into the bit-stream struct*/
speex_bits_read_from(&bits, (void*)[data bytes], [data length]);

/*Decode the data*/
speex_decode(state, &bits, tempBuffer.mData);
```

Same initialization as before

It crashes with no error at speex_decode. I checked the length of the input NSData and the output one and they are the same. Bytes inside are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Euh, so are you actually passing the *encoder* state to speex_decode()??